# LocationServices Runtime Error

Tags: android

I keep getting a Runtime exception (see below) 
and I really can't quite get the issue.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' attempting to access 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbce' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/app.puresecure-1/base.apk)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Unknown Source)
    at app.puresecure.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

This

```
at app.puresecure.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:20)
```

reffers to:

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


//this line!!
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this); 
}
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've programmed android but this might help you https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings. I think you may need to grant the application permission to use the device's location services.

Comment: I've already added the permissions in the manifest file

Comment: Have you gave all these permissions?

​<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />​
    ​<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>

Comment: yep, I double-checked that